# HTML Image not displayed

Tags: html, image

Amazon has a facility that generates HTML snippets for you to show images of products from their store.

However when running locally the image is not displayed, when run on jsbin it is.

The local code is:

```html
<a href="https://www.amazon.co.uk/Complete-Idiots-Guide-Creating-Page/dp/0789722569/ref=as_li_ss_il?ie=UTF8&qid=1506425682&sr=8-10&keywords=web+development+for+idiots&linkCode=li2&tag=valuehistor0e-21&linkId=fc910756748618e2854e81a581107b24" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="//ws-eu.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?_encoding=UTF8&ASIN=0789722569&Format=_SL160_&ID=AsinImage&MarketPlace=GB&ServiceVersion=20070822&WS=1&tag=valuehistor0e-21"></a><img src="https://ir-uk.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=valuehistor0e-21&l=li2&o=2&a=0789722569"
  width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important;" />
```

The JSBIN example is [here](https://jsbin.com/cigedub/edit?html,output).

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors?

Comment: Are you running the page as file or via a local server (ref. "src="//ws-eu.amazon*")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't state how you run the page: locally from file or via a local server.

In the former case all links with "//*" will adopt the protocol (e.g. "file://") which won't be a valid link.

You can hard-code the protocol instead:

```
<a href="https://www.amazon.co.uk/Complete-Idiots-Guide-Creating-Page/dp/0789722569/ref=as_li_ss_il?ie=UTF8&qid=1506425682&sr=8-10&keywords=web+development+for+idiots&linkCode=li2&tag=valuehistor0e-21&linkId=fc910756748618e2854e81a581107b24" target="_blank">
<!-- The img src below -->
<img border="0" src="https://ws-eu.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?_encoding=UTF8&ASIN=0789722569&Format=_SL160_&ID=AsinImage&MarketPlace=GB&ServiceVersion=20070822&WS=1&tag=valuehistor0e-21"></a>
<img src="https://ir-uk.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=valuehistor0e-21&l=li2&o=2&a=0789722569" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important;" />
```

Comment: I was running the code from a file. As you suggested changing the prefix  corrected the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Proper set `img` `src` tag in image url.

For example:

```
<a href="https://www.amazon.co.uk/Complete-Idiots-Guide-Creating-Page/dp/0789722569/ref=as_li_ss_il?ie=UTF8&qid=1506425682&sr=8-10&keywords=web+development+for+idiots&linkCode=li2&tag=valuehistor0e-21&linkId=fc910756748618e2854e81a581107b24" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg" width="1000" height="300"></a>
```